# Computation of $\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{e}^{a\cos\left(t\right)}\cos\left(mt\right)\,\mathrm{d}t$

Tags: integration

I would like to find the Fourier-Chebyshev series expansion of the function $\,\mathrm{f}\left(\,x\,\right) = \mathrm{e}^{ax}$.

So, I already have found $c_0 = I_0(a)$.
The second step is $c_n$. And I found that $$c_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{a\cos{t}}\cos\left(\,mt\,\right)\,\mathrm{d}t\,,\qquad \: a\in\mathbb{R}\,,\ m\in\mathbb{N}$$ 
Any ideas how to compute following integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a modified Bessel function of the first kind. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html